# How to let a column have values reflected automatically, when value is inserted/updated/deleted to/from another column in the same table?

Tags: oracle, view, triggers, oracle-xe, bind-variables

I created 2 tables : `INFORMATION` AND `FEED`.

```
INFORMATION has 2 attributes : ID(Primary Key), TOT_AMOUNT.

FEED has 4 attributes : ID(Foreign key refer INFORMATION(ID)), S_AMOUNT, S_DATE, TOT_REM.
```

Now, I have to insert/update/delete values to/from `TOT_REM`, based on the insertion/removal/update of `S_AMOUNT` and `TOT_AMOUNT`.

The sample contents are :

```
INFORMATION Table
------------------
ID   |  TOT_AMOUNT
1    |    100
2    |    20
3    |    50
...

               FEED Table
----------------------------------------
ID   |   S_AMOUNT   |  S_DATE  | TOT_REM 
1    |     10       |10.10.2010|   90
1    |     10       |13.10.2010|   80
1    |     30       |17.10.2013|   50
1    |     10       |20.10.2016|   40
...
```

We need to automatically insert the value into `TOT_REM` attribute, based on the update/insert/delete operation performed on `S_AMOUNT`, with the help of `TOT_AMOUNT` & `S_AMOUNT`.

At any time, TOT_REM can't be less than 0. And, TOT_REM needs to be automatically inserted/removed/updated such that

```
TOT_REM for i(at a specific date) = (TOT_AMOUNT for ID=i) - 
                                    SUM(S_AMOUNT of all instances of ID=i,
                                    which is later than the S_DATE for ID=i);
```

So, assuming if we delete the 2nd tuple(1,10,'13.10.2010',80), the reflected state of `BR_FEED` should be :

```
               FEED Table
----------------------------------------
ID   |   S_AMOUNT   |  S_DATE  | TOT_REM 
1    |     10       |10.10.2010|   90
1    |     30       |17.10.2013|   60
1    |     10       |20.10.2016|   50
...
```

I wrote a trigger, which fails showing

```
ORA-04091: table SSUMAN.FEED is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

The code for trigger is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BR_INSERT_TRB
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF S_AMOUNT ON FEED
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF DELETING THEN 
UPDATE  FEED bf
SET     bf.TOT_REM = bf.S_AMOUNT + :OLD.S_AMOUNT;
END IF;

IF INSERTING THEN 
INSERT INTO FEED (TOT_REM) VALUES(
((SELECT TOT_AMOUNT FROM INFORMATION bi WHERE bi.ID=:NEW.ID) - 
(SELECT SUM(S_AMOUNT) FROM FEED bf where bf.ID=:NEW.ID) - 
:NEW.S_AMOUNT);
END IF;

IF UPDATING THEN 
UPDATE  FEED bf
SET     bf.TOT_REM = (SELECT TOT_AMOUNT FROM BR_INFORMATION bi WHERE bi.ID=bf.ID) - 
(SELECT SUM(S_AMOUNT) FROM FEED bf where bf.ID=:NEW.ID) - 
 :NEW.S_AMOUNT
WHERE   :NEW.ID IS NOT NULL;
END IF;   

END;
```

Questions :

1. Is this approach flawed? Can't I achieve what I want, with this way?[OPTIONAL]
2. Is there any scope of bringing view here? I am not able to think in that line! Probably, lack of experience...[OPTIONAL]
3. Any better approach, so that TOT_REM values can be automatically reflected?[COMPULSORY TO ANSWER]

Comment: When you say "TOT_REM can't be less than 0" - do you mean that as part of the logic for calculating TOT_REM, or should the offending insert/update/delete be REJECTED because it would cause TOT_REM to become negative? The two are quite different and solved in different ways.

Comment: @mathguy - It should be rejected, thanks for asking for clarification. Any other detail required?

Comment: I see a few difficulties here. Biggest is the computation of TOT_REM at the beginning. If you delete the 10.10.2010 row, then TOT_REM in the following row needs to read from the INFORMATION table instead of from the row above it. If you add a row above the first one (above 10.10.2010), the 10.10.2010 TOT_ROM will need to be calculated based on the row above it instead of from INFORMATION. The bigger problem still: You reject a row because it would make TOT_ROM negative. At a later time, you remove a row with an older date... now do you need to bring back the row you rejected at first?

Comment: @mathguy - During deletion, it should work as addition won't create issues. During update of the TOT_REM, it should throw an error; while insertion, it should check and reject if the amount crosses the tot_rem --- MAYBE, if before-trigger may come to help. I can see the vision, but, just can't code the view definition. Lack of Experience in Oracle Pl/SQL.

Comment: I will add to my original answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to create view. Look at this

**Test data**

```
create table feed(ID,S_AMOUNT,S_DATE) as  (
  SELECT 1,10, TO_DATE('10.10.2010','dd.mm.yyyy') FROM dual UNION all
  SELECT 1,10,TO_DATE('13.10.2010','dd.mm.yyyy') FROM dual UNION all
  SELECT 1,30,TO_DATE('17.10.2013','dd.mm.yyyy') FROM dual UNION all
  SELECT 2,10,TO_DATE('20.10.2016','dd.mm.yyyy') FROM dual)

create table INFORMATION (id, TOT_AMOUNT) as (
  SELECT 1,100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,50 FROM DUAL)
```

**Query**

```
create or replace view result_feed as
  SELECT f.*,i.TOT_AMOUNT - NVL(SUM(S_AMOUNT) OVER(PARTITION BY f.ID ORDER BY f.S_DATE),0) AS tot_rem FROM FEED f, INFORMATION i
    WHERE f.ID = i.id
  ORDER BY f.ID, f.S_DATE;
  -- used NVL to prevent side-effect of null values


  SELECT * from RESULT_FEED;
```

Your approach with with trigger is not suitable in this situation. I think data is added seldom and query needed only in special cases. Of course there is some approaches to workaround mutating table(package variables,compound triggers, autonoumous transaction) but I think they only add perfomance problems to your database.

Comment: Thanks, this turned helpful, and solved my problem. Any reason why not to use virtual column, and to prefer view?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful  In this case I don't use virtual column because it is forbidden use analytic function in it.(I don't know how implement your logic with absence of analytic functions). For future: I will use virtual column if it is used as predicate in some complex query or use as constraint or for some purpose I need index on it. Some developers don't like views because as they say theirs business has complicated logic and better work with table instead of view. I used view in general as result of some report or some abstraction on user data.

Answer (score 1):

If this was my business problem, and I could start from scratch (which may not be possible in your case), I would keep the `INFORMATION` table as-is, I would remove the `TOT_REM` column from `FEED`, and I would create a view that looks like the current `FEED` table. You can write all the necessary logic in the view definition.

**ADDED**:

First, here is a view definition; it assumes the base tables `INFORMATION` and `FEED` are as described by the OP, with no `TOT_REM` column in `FEED`.

```
create view remaining_balance (id, s_amount, s_date, tot_rem) as
select i.id, f.s_amount, f.s_date, 
       i.tot_amount - nvl(sum(f.s_amount) over (partition by f.id order by f.s_date), 0)
from   information i left outer join feed f
                     on i.id = f.id
;
```

The view uses an outer join, to include the `id`'s from the `INFORMATION` table that don't have any corresponding rows in `FEED`. (Then, to deal with nulls in the computation of `TOT_REM`, I use the `nvl()` function to convert `NULL` to `0`.)

Here is an example of running the view:

```
 SQL> select * from information;

        ID TOT_AMOUNT
---------- ----------
         1        100
         2         20
         3         50

3 rows selected.

SQL> select * from feed;

        ID   S_AMOUNT S_DATE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10 2010-10-10
         1         10 2010-10-13
         1         30 2010-10-17
         1         10 2016-10-20

4 rows selected.

SQL> select * from remaining_balance order by id, s_date;

        ID   S_AMOUNT S_DATE        TOT_REM
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10 2010-10-10         90
         1         10 2010-10-13         80
         1         30 2010-10-17         50
         1         10 2016-10-20         40
         2                               20
         3                               50

6 rows selected.
```

Now, a well-established method to enforce complex constraints is to use materialized views. Outright check constraints only work at the row level and can't be used when conditions involve more than one table. In the current problem the check is against two tables, and `TOT_REM` depends on other rows in the `FEED` table - so a constraint in the `FEED` table wouldn't work anyway.

The materialized view approach is to define a view like the one I created, as a materialized view, to define it with `refresh fast on commit` (so that the constraints are checked immediately after DML operations on the base tables), and to create a check constraint on the materialized view. In the problem at hand, that would be a check on `TOT_RM >= 0`.

Alas, `refresh fast on commit` is prohibited (at least as recently as Oracle version 11.2, which is what I have), when the view definition uses analytic functions. I used the analytic version of the `sum()` function, so this won't work.

It seems to make sense, however, to define a different materialized view, like below:

```
create materialized view remaining_balance (id, tot_rem) as
select i.id, i.tot_amount - f.sum_s_amount
from   information i inner join (select   id, sum(s_amount) as sum_s_amount 
                                 from     feed 
                                 group by id) f
                     on i.id = f.id
;

SQL> select * from remaining_balance;

        ID    TOT_REM
---------- ----------
         1         40
```

I don't use an outer join anymore, since this is only supposed to show remaining balances. I assume `INFORMATION` has a check constraint on `TOT_AMOUNT` to make sure it is non-negative, and `id` in `FEED` is primary key pointing to `id` in `INFORMATION`, so there's no additional information revealed by an outer join for this version of the view. (However, if desired, it can be made to include all `id`'s).

Here you should be able to define the view with `refresh fast on commit` and to add a check constraint to the effect of `tot_rem >= 0`. Alas, I am not able to test it; advanced replication (required to create materialized view logs, which in turn are needed for `refresh fast`) is not available/enabled in the free Express version of Oracle I have. Try to experiment with this though - it may be the solution you need. Good luck!

Comment: Can you extend the view definition(code)? I was not able to design the definition for view.

Comment: I can, but it won't help if what you need is really a constraint, not just a reporting solution.

Comment: It is, indeed, a very nice answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't include the s_date part, because of which I am not able to achieve (what I wanted in  my FEED table). Thanks, anyways. Learnt several new things because of this answer of yours.